# next-intl selecting enum-based values not working

Tags: reactjs, next.js, internationalization, next-intl

I needed next-intl  translation for my next.js projenct (nextjs v13.4). Following official example on https://next-intl-docs.vercel.app/docs/usage/messages#selecting-enum-based-values

which stated

(in file en.json)

```
"message": "{gender, select, female {She} male {He} other {They}} is online."
```

and (in place of use)

```
t('message', {gender: 'female'});
```

It didn't work for some reason, not reading translation message well?

Answer (score 0):

Well it turned out that if I have another translation file, in my case

**sr.json** (Serbian)

equivalent values (for the same key) must be included in that file too, like in **en.json** file, there should be  no difference in order for this to work in an language.

Like:

```
"message": "{gender, select, female {Она} male {Oн} other {Oни}} је на мрежи."
```